# 1960s Novel Alien and ICBM Silo?

Tags: story-identification, novel, alien-invasion, mind-control

I vaguely recall reading a pulp novel in the 1960s about some sort of alien invasion. One man was immune to some sort of mind control (plate in his head?) and there was something about an ICBM silo. Does anyone have any idea what this novel might be?

(This is the first time I've posted here so apologies if I've broken any rules.)

Comment: Just in case you're confusing two stories, I'll mention that Stephen King's _The Tommyknockers_ has aliens taking over and a man with a plate in his head.

Answer (score 2):

Probably *not* the answer as there's no "alien invasion" in it, but a man with a plate in his head making him mindtalk-resistant and an abandoned ICBM silo both appear in *Spawn of the Death Machine* by Ted White (1968).

I see now that it was once published together with its 1965 prequel *Android Avenger* and a third book, *Invasion from 2500* (by White together with Terry Carr), in 1968. The third book just *might* be considered "a sort of alien invasion", but I feel it's all a bit too farfetched.

Comment: Google books blurb for the 3rd book sorta supports "alien invasion" - I assume the plot reveals they're actually from the future, not outer space ##Jack knew he had to get away and warn the country of the invasion. But before he could reach Chicago all the major cities in the United States had been conquered by the aliens.##

Comment: I found a brief description of "Invasion from 2500" and it could be the novel I'm thinking of. I'll investigate. Thank you!!  JM